# Issue getting SelectedKeys & switching the operations

Tags: java, sockets, nio

I have created this asynchronous client socket that connects to a server and keeps the connection open at all times and auto reconnects when disconnected from the server.

Anyway my problem is this :on initializing the connection I register the operation as a connect operation (`SelectionKey.OP_Connect`).

Now when I iterate between the selected keys of the selector, I am expecting it to enter the control statement isconnectable and change the operation as seen in the control statement.

unfortunately I'm not getting any selected keys whatsoever. Where could I be going wrong?

```
        import java.net.InetAddress;
    import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
    import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
    import java.nio.channels.SelectionKey;
    import java.nio.channels.Selector;
    import java.nio.channels.SocketChannel;
    import java.util.Iterator;
    import java.util.Set;
    import java.util.logging.Level;
    import java.util.logging.Logger;



    /*
     * @author kewin
     */
    public class clientEvent implements Runnable{
        private static volatile boolean connected=false;
        private SocketChannel channel;
        private Selector selector;
        private ByteBuffer readBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(8192);
        private QueueData Qdata;
        private SelectionKey selectKey;



        private  void initiateConnection() {
    try {
    selector= Selector.open();//initializes the Selector Thread
    channel = SocketChannel.open();
    channel.configureBlocking(false);
    channel.connect(new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1"),2000));
    Thread.sleep(50);//Sleeps for a few Seconds to allow decent connection completion
    channel.register(selector,SelectionKey.OP_CONNECT);//Registers the channel with the a selector and a selection key
    if(channel.finishConnect())/*checks whether the connection is finished*/{
        channel.register(selector,SelectionKey.OP_READ);//Registers the channel with the a selector and a selection key
        connected=true;}
   } catch(Exception ex){connected=false;} 
 }


        private void ConnectAndMonitor(){
           while(true){
            try {
               readBuffer.clear();
               channel.read(readBuffer);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                    connected=false
                try {
                    channel.close()
                    selector.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {         
                }
                   if(!connected){
                    initiateConnection();
                    connected=true;
               }
            }
           }
        }


        @Override
        public void run() {
            try{
                new Thread(){@Override public void run(){ConnectAndMonitor()}}.start(); 

                while(true){
                   if(!connected){
                       System.out.println("not connected");
                       Thread.sleep(500);
                   }
                   else{
                        selector.selectNow();
                                       Set Keys=selector.keys();
                                       Iterator iterator =Keys.iterator();
                        while(iterator.hasNext()){
                            SelectionKey key=(SelectionKey)iterator.next();

                            if(key.isConnectable()){
                                channel.register(selector,SelectionKey.OP_READ);
                                System.out.println("Connectable");
                                break;
                            }

                            if(key.isReadable()){
                                channel.register(selector,SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);
                                System.out.println("Readable");
                                break;
                            }

                            if(key.isWritable()){
                                channel.register(selector,SelectionKey.OP_CONNECT);
                                System.out.println("Writable");
                                break;
                            }
                            System.out.println("<<<<<<<<<>>>>>>>>>>>>");

                       }

                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                   }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex){
            }
        }

        public static void main(String[] args){
            new Thread(new clientEvent()).start();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do the connect in blocking mode it blocks and completes during the method call, so if you subsequently register it for OP_CONNECT, `isConnectable()` will never be true.

So if you must have non-blocking connects, which NB your code *is already doing without,* put the channel into non-blocking mode first, issue the `connect()`, register for OP_CONNECT, then when it fires *and* `finishConnect() returns true, deregister OP_CONNECT and register something else, or as you are a client more probably just start sending requests.

EDIT: Your edited code is incorrect in the following ways:

1. Remove the `Thread.sleep()`.
2. Move the `finishConnect()` call to the `isConnected()` case of your select loop.
3. When `OP_CONNECT/isConnectable()` fires, *deregister* OP_CONNECT.
4. Remove the `if(!connected)` test.

Most of this I have already said above. At the moment you are (a) giving the connection time to complete, (b) completing it, (c) waiting in the select loop for it to complete, (d) never deregistering `OP_CONNECT` even though you aren't interested in it any more, (e) never executing select() if you don't have a connection, and (f) trying to find completed connections in the select() loop. This doesn't make any sense whatsoever.

On the other hand if you don't mind waiting for the connection to complete inline where you are creating it, why do it in non-blocking mode at all? Do it in *blocking* mode, then `configureBlocking(false),` then register for `OP_READ/OP_WRITE` and forget about `OP_CONNECT`, `isConnectable()`, and `finishConnect()` altogether.

Comment: Hi @EJP Ok correct me if I am wrong  but you say that I should put the channel in non-blocking mode? From The code I can see that I have put the channel as 
'channel.configureBlocking(false);'
with that said I have also done what you said , that is
"issue the connect(), register for OP_CONNECT, then when it fires and `finishConnect() returns true, deregister OP_CONNECT and register something else" but still no effect on the iterator.still shows that there are o selectedKeys